# MongoDB Aggregtation Pipleline using Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have a collection Employee and has the following records in it

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Scott",
    "company": "Google"
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Steven",
    "company": "Yahoo"
}

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adam",
    "company": "Facebook"
}
```

Any suggestions on what kind of mongodb aggregation pipeline has to be used in order to split the data based on the common field id. For the above example, I would be getting two records as my outcome one which contains key as id 1 with the corresponding list of associated values and the other with the key as 2.

Comment: You need a $group stage. Please look at the linked dups. Should be `TypedAggregation<YourPojo> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(YourPojo.class,
               Aggregation.group("id").
               push("$$ROOT").as("matches"));`